# Can I get SVN log over http request on Assembla server?

Tags: svn, http, logging

Is it possible to access an svn log without having svn installed? I'm trying to access a log of recently changed (committed) files on Assembla, but the hosted web server from which I'd like to send this request doesn't have svn installed. Since all I'm doing is sending the svn server a few parameters like my name, password, output format, revision dates and the like, I don't see why there shouldn't be a simple http request mode for svn (e.g. with basic authentication) that would allow me to get the log file even if I don't have a special program (svn) installed on the hosted server from which I would like to send my svn log request.

Does any one know if this is possible with svn in general or with Assembla in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Assembla, but Subversion has native support for the WebDAV protocol (which is a superset of HTTP). If the URL of your repository begins with `http://` then it's WebDAV compatible and can be accessed with a standard web browser. Unfortunately this only gives you access to files in the repository, not the history information. If you need more features you should consider using a web application which integrates with Subvesion, like [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/).

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your quick reply. The URL of my repository at Assembla does in deed contain http(s!), and it looks like Assembla uses Trac as well, but so far all I have read about trac mentions a ticketing system for bug reports. Can you give me an idea of where to look to find an explanation of how to use trac as a http-accessible substitute for "svn log"?

Comment: Trac has a Timeline feature that shows, among others, history of a Subversion repository. You can find an example on the Trac homepage http://bit.ly/bN4hlj